# Subquery issue with null records in left table

Tags: sql, subquery

Running into a bit of a problem.

```
SELECT
Q1.LOCATION_ID,
Q1.LAST_DATE,
Q1.SHIPMENT_LINE_STATUS_CODE
FROM Q1
WHERE
Q1.LAST_DATE =
(   SELECT
    MAX(Q2.LAST_DATE)
    FROM
    Q2
    WHERE
    Q2.LOCATION_ID = Q1.LOCATION_ID
    AND
    Q2.SHIPMENT_LINE_STATUS_CODE = 'RECEIVED'
)
```

The problem is if there is no "RECEIVED; on the SHIPMENT_LINE_STATUS_CODE, I get no records.

For example, I want to show the following:

```
LOCATION_ID   LAST_UPDATE_DATE     SHIPMENT_LINE_STATUS_CODE
4544                 4/1/2021                       RECEIVED
4876                 NULL                            NULL
```

However, I only get this:

```
LOCATION_ID   LAST_UPDATE_DATE     SHIPMENT_LINE_STATUS_CODE
4544                 4/1/2021                       RECEIVED
```

I need to return the records that are NULL when the SHIPMENT_LINE_STATUS_CODE is not 'RECEIVED'

Comment: So you also want to include rows from Q1 where there are no corresponding rows in Q2? You should research UNION and EXISTS statements.

Comment: you didn't explain what's the logic to chose that other row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite this using a `LEFT JOIN` which would return the results from `Q1` and matching results only from `Q2`:

```
SELECT  Q1.LOCATION_ID,
        Q1.LAST_DATE,
        Q1.SHIPMENT_LINE_STATUS_CODE
  FROM  Q1
    LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT  LOCATION_ID,
                      MAX(LAST_DATE) AS LAST_DATE
                FROM  Q2
                WHERE SHIPMENT_LINE_STATUS_CODE = 'RECEIVED'
                GROUP BY LOCATION_ID
              ) a ON a.LOCATION_ID = Q1.LOCATION_ID AND a.LAST_DATE = Q1.LAST_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

How about with a CTE and `LEFT JOIN`?...

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT LOCATION_ID,
    MAX(Q2.LAST_DATE) AS LAST_DATE
    FROM
    Q2
    WHERE Q2.SHIPMENT_LINE_STATUS_CODE = 'RECEIVED'
    GROUP BY LOCATION_ID
    )
SELECT
Q1.LOCATION_ID,
Q1.LAST_DATE,
Q1.SHIPMENT_LINE_STATUS_CODE
FROM Q1
LEFT JOIN CTE on Q1.LAST_DATE = CTE.LAST_DATE AND Q1.LOCATION_ID = CTE.LOCATION_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is ambiguous but If I understand correctly you wanna show this :

```
SELECT
   Q1.LOCATION_ID,
   Q1.LAST_DATE,
   Q1.SHIPMENT_LINE_STATUS_CODE
FROM Q1
WHERE Q1.LAST_DATE =
(   SELECT MAX(Q2.LAST_DATE)
    FROM Q2
    WHERE Q2.LOCATION_ID = Q1.LOCATION_ID
      AND Q2.SHIPMENT_LINE_STATUS_CODE = 'RECEIVED'
)
or Q1.SHIPMENT_LINE_STATUS_CODE is null
```